# How to call the Runnable in the other calss?

Tags: android, runnable

I add the `runnable` in the `count fragment` like the following code.

```
public static Runnable getTime = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Long spentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Long minius = (spentTime/1000)/60;
        Long seconds = (spentTime/1000) % 60;
        RecordTime.setText(record_time_text + minius + ":" + seconds);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

And I want call the `runnable` in the other `class`

But it can not call `runnable` by `count.getTime` .

How to call the `Runnable` in the other `calss` ?

Comment: Did you try `count.getTime.run()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it in static way. If class is `Count` then `Count.getTime.run()` should work. Hope it helps!